# How to have a different program ID depending on the cluster?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

Is there a way have anchor check the correct program ID owner of an account depending on which cluster the program has been deployed to?

Currently I have to manually check both program IDs, the devnet and mainnet program IDs, to see whether the account has the correct owner.

There must be a built in solana or anchor way of switching between the program IDs at compile time?

```
let owner = *aggregator.owner;
if owner != SWITCHBOARD_V2_DEVNET && owner != SWITCHBOARD_V2_MAINNET {
 return Err(error!(FeedErrorCode::InvalidSwitchboardAccount));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Rust's [features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) mechanism and `cfg` expressions, you can programmatically specify the program/crate ID at build time to avoid the need for such manual checks:

- for instance in the program's `lib.rs` (before the `#[program]` macro) the code below will declare one ID or the other depending on the `mainnet` feature being enabled or not:

```
#[cfg(feature = "mainnet")]
declare_id!("8ghymvPffJbkLHqYfSKdE8moRH5gSf4AQav9qtZfu77H");
#[cfg(not(feature = "mainnet"))]
declare_id!("DLANS7Qh31fFWLujEMtn5kyd87H8ZUbhwtfMurrSHYn9");
```

- in the program's `Cargo.toml` the code below will declare the `mainnet` feature (here disabled by default):

```
[features]
mainnet = []
```

This way you can choose to build for mainnet or no by passing the `--features "mainnet"` option to `anchor build`. The crate ID baked in will be the relevant one, and Anchor will then be able to perform the check against that only, correct ID for that deployment.

Comment: yes is is how jet also does it i believe, rust features are godsend, helps a lot to test program which have admin features via upgradeable loaders on test environments such as programtest crate where support for upgradeable loaders is not there :(